# private ip is accessible from node but not from pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a k8s cluster on google cloud. I want to connect to cloud sql postgres using private ip from one of my pod just for testing purpose.

I'm able to access private ip from the node but not from pod. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This GitHub Issue details the issue fully, but you essentially need to utilize a VPC Native GKE cluster so that way the cluster's network is bridged to the Cloud SQL instance's network.

The full command below is an example pulled from the VPC Native documentation, but essentially you'll need to utilize the `--enable-ip-alias`, `--subnetwork` `--cluster-secondary-range-name` and `--services-secondary-range-name` flags to get the cluster to be properly configured using the underlying GCP network.

```
gcloud container clusters create CLUSTER_NAME \
    --region=COMPUTE_REGION \
    --enable-ip-alias \
    --subnetwork=SUBNET_NAME \
    --cluster-ipv4-cidr=POD_IP_RANGE \
    --services-ipv4-cidr=SERVICES_IP_RANGE
```

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-config-connector/issues/201#issuecomment-640106267